# Torsocks prevent starting firefox and using sudo

Tags: fedora, sudo, firefox, tor

I recently activated torsocks with `source torsocks on` and then restarted my Fedora 37 machine. After that I wasn't able to execute any commands as `sudo` anymore with the message `/usr/bin/sudo: Operation not permitted` and Firefox didn't start anymore. I only torified my terminal. After `source torsocks off` everything worked again and I was able to start Firefox. Is this a bug or a failed configuration especially in Fedora because this didn't happened with Debian.